# Is there a good online French dictionary?

Tags: webapp-rec

It should be accurate and well made. Search history would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by *good*?  Everyone has their own definition.  Perhaps some details on what features you're looking for, what you've found, and why you don't like what you've found?

Comment: Besides having accurate translations, I'd like that it's usable and well made.

At one point I found a nice dictionary with history but I don't remember how it's called

I like CNRTL and WordReference so far.

Comment: please edit your question to reflect the information in your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a monolingual dictionary, the standard online reference is the
[Trésor de la Langue Française (TLF)](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv4/showps.exe?p=combi.htm;java=no;). You can search by pronunciation and browse the list of words. It's a reference dictionary, somewhat lacking in recent words.

A good list of resources for French from countries other than France is http://www.lexilogos.com/francophonie_dictionnaires.htm

[Tennessee Bob's Famous French Links](http://www.utm.edu/departments/french/french.html) links to various resources on France and French.

CRISCO has a [dictionary of synonyms](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/cgi-bin/cherches.cgi).

Multiple-language resources include [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/) (the French entries tend to be very basic, even [in French](http://fr.wiktionary.org/)), as well as [LOGOS](http://www.logosdictionary.eu/).

For English-French bilingual resources, start with the [Language Portal of Canada](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/index-eng.php) and EU portals such as the [Translation and language help for small businesses](http://ec.europa.eu/small-business/support/translation/index_en.htm) and the [Language resources and useful links for French](http://ec.europa.eu/translation/french/french_en.htm).

For translations of technical terms, your first stop should be Wikipedia. Another good resource is [IATE, the EU's multilingual term base](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/switchLang.do?success=mainPage&lang=en).

Comment: Nice selection. On en apprend tous les jours...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's quite a few. However my crystal ball is broken and I can't see clearly what are your needs. Check out the following ones:

- [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire%3aPage_d%27accueil) - quality varies, however sometimes very interesting information can be found
- [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/) - simple, yet effective (+ forums)
- [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) - good for tracking the history
- [BabLa](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/)
- [Reverso](http://www.reverso.net/text_translation.aspx?lang=EN)

This list is by no means exhaustive.

*BTW. Why is this question (related to learning a language) in the WebApplications stack?*

Comment: Because it's asking for a webapp?

Comment: Ok, thanks, somehow my perception got skewed, and word WebApplication reminds me only of development.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is: http://www.granddictionnaire.com

It has all of the very technical terms in any arcane domain you could think of.
Maintained by the Quebec government, which has to translate everything they do.

When you search for a term, it will show the definitions in all domains that apply (for instance: électroacoustique, robinetterie industrielle, génie mécanique, armée, etc).